# PHP ftp_get Permission denied

Tags: php, ftp, chmod, permission-denied

Im new in PHP and I'm using this code to download a image from a ftp to my Desktop:

```
    // try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "<p> Connected as " . $ftp_user . " " . $ftp_server . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p> Couldn't connect as" . $ftp_user . "</p>";
}

$local_file = "C:\Users\sam\Desktop";
$server_file = "ftp://md346645@188.93.148.30/public/sites/www.ronvanderwerf.com/Images/beeld.jpg";

// download server file
if (ftp_get( $conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
{
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
}
```

I am running this code on XAMPP. Unfortunately, this is what I get:

```
*Connected as md346645 188.93.148.30*

*Warning: ftp_get(C:\Users\sam\Desktop): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website ron\index.php on line 34*

*Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening C:\Users\sam\Pictures in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website ron\index.php on line 34*
*Error downloading ...md346645@188.93.148.30/public/sites/www.ronvanderwerf.com/Images/beeld.jpg.*
```

It seems to me that I have to chmod my `$local_file` to give permission. Unfortunately I did not succeed to accomplish that.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Well, you are saying the solution to your problem in your question. Your webserver is running with a user who doesnt have write permissions to your desktop. Make sure that the user running web server can write to sams desktop, and you will be golden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the ftp_get function is a file name, not a directory. This code is actually trying to save the image into the file "C:\Users\sam\Desktop", which is of course not a file and I guess Windows doesn't allow anything to happen to this precious folder...

You just have to add the correct filename, try this :

```
$local_file = "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\theimage.jpg";
```

or, with only the filename if you want the image to be saved in the current folder :

```
$local_file = "theimage.jpg";
```